# Remove element from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to php and i want to remove element from array Here is my array:

```
Array
(
[Total] => 21600000
[Items] => Array
    (
        [2-13] => Array
            (
                [Item] => 2
                [PID] => 13
                [UPrice] => 11000000
                [Qty] => 1
                [Total] => 11000000
            )

        [58-167] => Array
            (
                [Item] => 58
                [PID] => 167
                [UPrice] => 5300000
                [Qty] => 1
                [Total] => 5300000
            )

    )

)
```

And i want to remove array element by `PID`.
I have try this but no luck:-

```
    $ShoppingBag =$_SESSION['ssss'];        

    if ($ShoppingBag !== null && $ShoppingBag['Total'] > 0) {          
        foreach ($ShoppingBag['Items'] as $IOrder) {               

          if($IOrder["PID"]==13)
          {                 
              unset($ShoppingBag[$IOrder]);

          }else
          {

          }
        }
    }
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: You unset `$IOrder` variable but it doesn't actually modify the original array. Pass it by reference: `foreach ($ShoppingBag['Items'] as & $IOrder) {` — notice the `&` added before `$IOrder`.

Comment: do you want to remove every  `PID` element or only `PID` with value "13"

Comment: i want to remove [2-13] array if PID value 13

Comment: @MohitArora - Have you tried my provided [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23992778/696364) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with one simple array map :)

```
$arr = [
    'Total' => 21600000,
    'Items' => [
                '2-13' => [
                        'Item' => 2,
                        'PID' => 13,
                        'UPrice' => 11000000,
                        'Qty' => 1,
                        'Total' => 11000000
                ],
                '58-167'=> [
                        'Item' => 58,
                        'PID' => 167,
                        'UPrice' => 5300000,
                        'Qty' => 1,
                        'Total' => 5300000
                ]
            ]
    ];

$test = array_map(function($ar) { 
    foreach($ar as $k=>$i) { 
        if( isset($i['PID']) && $i['PID'] == '13') 
            unset($ar[$k]); 
    } 
    return $ar; } , $arr);

var_dump($test);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need 2 loop to do the action you want.

```
foreach($my_array as $key=>$value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
    {
       foreach($value as $k=>$v)
       {
         if($k == 'PID')
         {
             unset($value[$k]);
         }
       }
   }
}
```

with this you can remove only element with key PID.

Comment: reason for downvote? This is a legit answer explain the reason for down vote

Comment: It doesn't work, the `$k` variable will be PID for both rows, but they don't want to remove all of them, they want to remove entries with a PID of a specific value.

Comment: so we can check with value for example if $v == 13 then use unset.

Comment: @scragar: this is a generic answer tho i didnt answer it but i think it clears the intention fairly so i dont see a point on downvoting it just for specific reason

Answer (score 2):

Hi youre unsetting the $IOrder instead of the Item that you want to delete:
This code is a solution an i tested it :

```
$ShoppingBag = Array
(
"Total" => 21600000,
"Items" => Array
    (
        "2-13" => Array
            (
                "Item" => 2,
                "PID" => 13,
                "UPrice" => 11000000,
                "Qty" => 1,
                "Total" => 11000000,
            ),

        "58-167" => Array
            (
                "Item" => 58,
                "PID" => 167,
                "UPrice" => 5300000,
                "Qty" => 1,
                "Total" => 5300000,
            ),

    ),

);

foreach($ShoppingBag["Items"] as $key => $value){
    if($value["PID"]==13){
        unset($ShoppingBag["Items"][$key]);
    }
}
```

You should know that always when you're using foreach loop the foreach( $a as $b ) when you do something to $b , $a remains the same because tey are different variables :)
Hope it will help you .

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [
    'Total' => 21600000,
    'Items' => [
                '2-13' => [
                        'Item' => 2,
                        'PID' => 13,
                        'UPrice' => 11000000,
                        'Qty' => 1,
                        'Total' => 11000000
                ],
                '58-167'=> [
                        'Item' => 58,
                        'PID' => 167,
                        'UPrice' => 5300000,
                        'Qty' => 1,
                        'Total' => 5300000
                ]
            ]
    ];

$pid_to_remove = 13;

$new_ar = array_filter(
    $arr,
    function ($v) using ($pid_to_remove) {
        return (!isset($v['PID'])) || ($v['PID'] != $pid_to_remove);
    }
);
```